# (discord.py) How can I get a list of how many permissions a user has

Tags: python, list, discord, discord.py

I am currently making a "userinfo" command for my bot which returns general stuff like the user's ID, roles, profile picture, etc. And I also wanted it to display a list of how many permissions the mentioned user has. Here's the part of the code where I defined `member` just for context:

```
@client.command(aliases=["whois"])
async def userinfo(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
    if not member:  # if member is no mentioned
        member = ctx.message.author  # set member as the author
    ...
```

I am aware that you can do `member.guild_permissions.<permission>` which returns whether the user has a permission or not but I wanted to know if there was a way to just get a list of how many permissions a user has without having to check for every permission.

So is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually use [`Member.guild_permissions`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=guild_perm#discord.Member.guild_permissions):

```py
@client.command(aliases=["whois"])
async def userinfo(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
    if not member:
        member = ctx.message.author
    perm_list = [perm[0] for perm in member.guild_permissions if perm[1]]
```

`Member.guild_permission` returns a list of tuples (eg. `(manage_permissions, True)`). You can explore this list and add the permission to another list if it is `True`.